# How to change the position add column from bottom top top of the grid view

Tags: c#, datagridview

I created a CRUD functionality inside the grid view of my winforms in c# everything is okay but i want to position of the column that responsible for adding a new data into top because i don't want to scroll down every-time i add a new data. Any suggestions guys?

Comment: Could you add your code please ?

Comment: I think this is not possible in winforms. Instead put a add button above the grid, show a dialog and let the user enter the data, or let the button select the new data row and call ScrollIntoView.